# ASP.NET area in IIS 7 on windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net, .net

I don't see ASP.NET "area". In Add Remove programs I see .net framework 3.5 and WSE installed. May be I need particulary install the ASP.NET, but I don't know where I do this.
In Windows 7 I have this area (abowe IIS and Management areas).

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable ASP.NET in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008

In Windows 7, you can enable ASP.NET from `Control Panel` -> `Programs` -> `Programs and Features` -> `Turn Windows features on or off`. Expand `Internet Information Services` -> `World Wide Web Services` -> `Application Development Features` and click `ASP.NET`.

In Windows Server 2008, Open `Server Manager` -> click `Roles` -> click `Add Roles` -> select `Web Server (IIS)` -> in Role Services click `ASP.NET` it will prompt for necessary dependent Roles Services `click Add Required Role Services`.

Comment: I also had to close and reopen Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager application.